# simplify this SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql request :

```
SELECT pl.*, l.loyer, l.charges, l.locataire_id, laire.nom, laire.prenom,
       l.chambre_id, c.numero, c.etage, c.maison_id, m.titre_crm 
FROM
    (
    SELECT spl.id, spl.location_id, spl.mois, spl.annee, spl.loyer_paye
    from locations sl 
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT * FROM paiement_loyer 
            union 
            SELECT 9999, usl.id, (MONTH(NOW())-1), YEAR(NOW()), 0 
            FROM locations usl 
            WHERE usl.id not in (SELECT location_id FROM paiement_loyer) || 
                                (select count(*) FROM paiement_loyer
                                 WHERE location_id = usl.id AND annee = YEAR(NOW())
              AND mois=(MONTH(NOW())-1) ) = 0
            ) spl ON sl.id = spl.location_id
    where sl.date_debut <= CURDATE() && CURDATE() <= sl.date_fin
    ) pl
JOIN locations l ON pl.location_id = l.id
JOIN locataires laire ON l.locataire_id = laire.id
JOIN chambres c ON l.chambre_id = c.id
JOIN maisons m ON c.maison_id = m.id
ORDER BY trim(upper(m.titre_crm)), c.numero, annee, mois
```

I would like to simplify it, do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Tag dbms used, some non-ANSI SQL there...

Comment: What's non-ANSI SQL please ?

Comment: ANSI SQL is the SQL standard specification. Some parts of your SQL code is product specific (not a part of the SQL standard). If you tells us which database product you are using, you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: sorry, I'm using MYSQL.  Thank you.

Comment: Something weird here; `WHERE usl.id not in (SELECT location_id FROM paiement_loyer) || ...`. I get a syntax error... What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly is it code suppose to do? we are not here to read it and learn it.. post table structures input and desired output and then we'll be able to simplify it better

Comment: you're right, I modify my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt at cleaning it up. Note that I think the first LEFT OUTER JOIN could probably be swapped to an INNER JOIN.

I have swapped the 2nd UNIONed query to 2 queries, and for those I have changed them to use LEFT OUTER JOINs which then check that there isn't a match

```
SELECT pl.id, pl.location_id, pl.mois, pl.annee, pl.loyer_paye, 
        l.loyer, l.charges, l.locataire_id, laire.nom, laire.prenom,
       l.chambre_id, c.numero, c.etage, c.maison_id, m.titre_crm 
FROM
(
    SELECT spl.id, spl.location_id, spl.mois, spl.annee, spl.loyer_paye
    FROM locations sl 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, location_id, mois, annee, loyer_paye
        FROM paiement_loyer 
        UNION 
        SELECT 9999, usl.id, (MONTH(NOW())-1), YEAR(NOW()), 0
        FROM locations usl 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN paiement_loyer pl1
        ON usl.id = pl1.location_id 
        WHERE pl1.location_id IS NULL
        SELECT 9999, usl.id, (MONTH(NOW())-1), YEAR(NOW()), 0
        FROM locations usl 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN paiement_loyer pl2
        ON usl.id = pl1.location_id 
        AND pl2.annee = YEAR(NOW()) 
        AND pl2.mois=(MONTH(NOW())-1)
        WHERE pl2.location_id IS NULL
    ) spl ON sl.id = spl.location_id
    WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN sl.date_debut AND sl.date_fin
) pl
JOIN locations l ON pl.location_id = l.id
JOIN locataires laire ON l.locataire_id = laire.id
JOIN chambres c ON l.chambre_id = c.id
JOIN maisons m ON c.maison_id = m.id
ORDER BY TRIM(UPPER(m.titre_crm)), c.numero, pl.annee, pl.mois
```